# Google map API won't show

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I cannot get google maps in my view

## Code

```
// html
<div id="map"></div>


// css
html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
        height: 100%;
    }

// scripts

<script async defer 
                    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=PLACED MY CODE HERE... &callback=initMap"></script>
<script>
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
            zoom: 8
        });
    }
</script>
```

## RESULT

Nothing shows in my view & no error in console or network tab.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use a valid  width too  eg:  (just for test)

```
// css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#map {
    height: 640px;
    width:800px;
}
```

Comment: now i see the map but i get errors this time, **on map** `This page cant load Google Maps correctly. Do you own this website?` **on console** `You have exceeded your request quota for this API.`

Comment: for this you should check how your google maps key is configurated .. if you have some resctriction  on this key  ..

Comment: the issue was key limitation apparently google allows only 1 request per day!! which was burn during testing :))) damn google.

Comment: check better if you have a valid google maps  key   and your real config because 
 for what i know the google maps  policy  .for javascript library is for 28.000  free access in  a month  ..